# Disable voiceover on login

Tags: macos, voiceover

I bought a used Mac from someone who was using VoiceOver on the login screen.

I don't have any handicap, and I would like to disable VoiceOver, which I personally find annoying.

Strangely, VoiceOver is ONLY on the login screen, and I can't find an option to disable it *anywhere* on the computer. Also VoiceOver seems to come along with some sort of highlighting and on screen text.

Any help? I am running on Lion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being enabled only on the Login Screen you must disable it under **System Preferences / Users & Groups**. If the preferences are locked, click the lock icon in the lower-left corner of the page and type and administrator password to unlock them. Click **Login Options** and uncheck the *Use VoiceOver at Login Window*.

VoiceOver, along with other features of this kind, can be enabled, and hence disabled, under **System Preferences / Universal Access**.