# On-screen text unexpectedly read to me, despite Voiceover (Mac) being disabled

Tags: macos, mac, voiceover

On Mavericks, I have Voiceover turned off in both Accessibility settings and [Users & Groups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/disable-voiceover-on-login).

In the past week, Voiceover has started occasionally reading small bits of text to me, seemingly unrequested.

It seems to primarily be subject lines of new mail in Gmail (running as a webpage in Chrome), but this could be a red herring.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or trackpad gesture that I'm accidentally doing to make this happen? What could be going on?

[**Update**: see comments - I'm now certain it's *only* emails that are getting read aloud, but not sure whether it's anything to do with Chrome or not. OS-level email integration?]

Comment: Seems a long shot, but something introduced in 10.9.4?

Comment: Similar issue with 10.9.4 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6441450

Comment: Please check option in the "Text to Speech" tab of "System Prefrences" > "Dictation & Speech"... PS you may need to tick & untick the checkbox in order to solve the issue.

Comment: You specifically mention Chrome, but have you noticed it reading text from **any** other application?

Comment: Good point, @jer-el. Can't tell if it only happens when Chrome's open (it's always open!), but it's definitely only reading subject lines of new mail, whether I have Gmail open in a tab or not. So I've been wondering if it's to do with OS-level email integration. No luck messing with Mail.app or Internet Accounts in System Preferences.

Comment: Ok so if it only happens with gMail acount then the problem may be gMail settings : http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1075549&ctx=mail || https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en&ref_topic=3434353

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Read [this Apple Discussions article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3976896?start=0&tstart=0).

I think this is the same problem you are having.

> I think I got it. I was sitting at the screen when a message popped up with the voice over. There was a little spanner icon in the top right which allowed me to turn off this feature.

Comment: Sounds like a similar problem to mine, but I'm not getting onscreen notifications so have no spanner icon to click on!

Comment: Ok, I'll look for more.

Comment: Wait, you have the chrome notification menu item, right?

Comment: In the menu bar? Yep, and Gmail notifications is unchecked there. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So the bell has a red line across it?