# VoiceOver keeps turning on

Tags: macos, voiceover

My Macbook Pro (Touchpad, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) turns VoiceOver on intermittently. It's annoying.

It seems to happen at random, every few weeks. It happened today when the machine started up and I wasn't touching the keyboard. It had happened before whilst I was using the machine.

It's disabled in the system preferences. It's not in my user's [startup items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/disable-voiceover-on-login). The chances of me triggering it by "pressing command and pressing the touch id three times" is zero. So I'm not sure what could be triggering it.

I fear it may be faulty hardware or buggy software. That wouldn't surprise me, but I can't see many other posts out there, so I don't think it's a systematic problem. It's too intermittent that I feel like I could get anything useful from an Apple service.

Any ideas what else could be causing it to activate or, failing that, how to prevent it or debug the trigger?

Comment: Are there any other user accounts on this MacBook Pro?

Comment: Good question, but no.

Answer (score 1):

You can also turn on VoiceOver with the keyboard command cmd + F5 or cmd + function + 5. Might you be pressing those keys?

You can also tell Siri to turn on VoiceOver. I don't think this is your problem though.

Answer (score 1):

My mother had a similar issue, and it turned out to be that some switches were on in System Settings>Spoken Content.

We'd been assuming (wrongly) that all these "read text out loud" settings would be under VoiceOver. Figured I'd post an answer for all others who might arrive here from Google with similar problems :)