# Disable annoying voiceover: "Use the tab key to navigate..."

Tags: mac

I'm on macOS Mojave.

When I mistype my login password, I usually get a voiceover of something along the lines of: "Use the tab key to navigate..."

How do I permanently disable this?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/disable-voiceover-on-login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable voiceover on login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/disable-voiceover-on-login)